# Is there a way to Union Tables if one table is not yet created?

Tags: sql, union

A new table is created monthly which holds all the data for transactions within that month.  For certain reports, I must union all of the tables thru a SQL script as the new tables become available.  I would like to be pre-emptive and call out a table (standardized naming convention is used i.e. Table2023M9, Table20223M10) that has not yet been created in the DB.

```
SELECT*
 FROM
(SELECT [company] 
      ,[Account] 
      ,[2023M9] as Amount
      ,'2023M9' as [Period]
  From Table2023M9

Union all

SELECT [company] 
      ,[Account] 
      ,[2023M10] as Amount
      ,'2023M10' as [Period]
  From Table2023M10 /*Table doesn't exist yet.*/

 UNPIVOT (Amount FOR [Period] in (
       [2023M9]
      ,[2023M10] as 2023Table)
```

As Transactions

Is there a way to do this?

I tried the following:

```
Declare @Temp TABLE( Entity nvarchar (100) )

if ('Table2023M9') is not null

insert into @Temp
select Company
from Table23M1;

union all

if ('Table2023M10') is not null

insert into @Temp
select Company
from Table2023M10;

select * from @Temp
```

However, I still get the error message that the table doesn't exist.

Comment: No unioning to a table that isnt there. Fwiw that sounds like an insane system.

Comment: What result do you expect your `if(<literal string>) is NOT NULL` statements to produce?

Comment: Why are you creating a new table each month - rather that inserting into a single table that has a date/month column?

Comment: I was told it is because the data push is based on the source system's workflow (which is set to monthly). Therefore, the data pushes can only be done in the same monthly format i.e. one table for each month.

Comment: What is the sound of one hand clapping?

Comment: Data is pushed by what process from where? Import to one table, even if you have to use an intermediate 'temp' table which is purged for each event.